# FQL Query from Facebook Error ("must be an indexed column")

Tags: javascript, facebook-fql

I am trying to run the following FQL query for Facebook:

```
FB.api({
method:'fql.query',
query:'SELECT username FROM page WHERE type IN ("Musician/band")'},
function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

When running this, I get the following error in the javascript console:

```
"Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql "
```

I have checked this page, and type does not have a star next to it.  I am not not allowed to search through FB pages by category using FQL?  Or is there another way to write this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not indexable then you cannot index it. It must have a star next to it.

You can try using

```
SELECT username FROM page WHERE CONTAINS("Musician/band")
```

Comment: This definitely worked, but it didn't return as many fields as I thought it would.  Any idea why this would be?

Comment: @user1072337 probably to do with the fact that it's not bring indexed and ` contains` filters on all fields making the query not as efficient.